# Magento 1.9 RWD Theme - Product Image Scroll

Tags: php, jquery, css, magento, magento-1.9.1

I have a serious problem with the Magento 1.9 new theme (RWD) on mobile media only and wondered if anyone might be able to shed any light please, if I'm honest, I'm not even sure where to start troubleshooting this one.

If you view the product detail page on a mobile phone (or on Chrome emulation mode).
http://magento19.my.phpcloud.com/index.php/tori-tank-581.html

Click on one of the alternative product images and then try and scroll down on the page, you can't it is completely stuck, it will only allow you to scroll if you use the white space either side, or below the image.

I'd be massively grateful for any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if you made any CSS changes to overflow visibility... We had a small gutter on the right in our rwd templates. We "fixed" this by making a css change to the overflow. This simple change caused the no-scroll/jerky-scroll that made the page look partially rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in _catalog-product.scss:

```
@include bp(max-width, $bp-medium) {
.product-img-box {
    .product-image {
         pointer-events: none;
    }
}
.zoomContainer {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

}

This one helped me.